# How to show hidden files in Aptana's Project View?

Tags: aptana

I understand that Aptana is built from Eclipse. I tried searching for the Package Explorer to enable viewing of .htaccess files inside the project but I can't find the Package Explorer.

Any help of the exact location on how to enable it will be excellent.

Comment: for a solution, see http://superuser.com/questions/99035/aptana-show-htaccess-files , https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/841-viewing-and-editing-htaccess-files , http://pedroposada.com/blog/make-.htaccess-files-visible-aptana-studio.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**For Aptana 2**
In the project view, click the little down arrow in the top right hand corner, click on 'Filters' and in here you can tick which hidden files you want to view.

**For Apatana 3**
[See the answer by Frederick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166755/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-aptanas-project-view/8016746#8016746)

Comment: In Aptana 3 it's little down arrow > 'Customize View' > 'Filters'; however there doesn't seem to be an option relating to hidden files.

Comment: Hm.. anybody knows an option how to do this in Aptana 3?

Comment: This is not a correct answer for the latest version of aptana!!

Comment: I no longer use Aptana, but there have been some downvotes on this answer recently. I've updated the answer to address this.

Answer (score 94):

In Aptana 3 it's little down arrow > 'Customize View' > 'Filters' - uncheck .* files to show files like .htaccess and .* resources to show folders like .settings/

Comment: Clear answer to something so deceptive. *Uncheck* to show? Aptana's hints are rather vague. The tiny arrow and 'Customize View' didn't help much at all. Good example - 'how not to do it' - for lectures about usability.

Comment: I'm on linux and I need to deactivate the _.* files_ AND the _.* ressources_ filter to see any dot-files or -directories.

Comment: Just to clarify: In Aptana 3, ensure the project is selected in the Project Explorer, then click the little down arrow at the side of the Project Explorer pane...[continue from answer]

Answer (score 38):

...geez, it took me a while to find that damn arrow :)  Sell below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing an image, without your visual description, I wouldn't have made it!

Comment: You saved me from hours of useless searching  :)

Answer (score 17):

I'm using Aptana 3 on a Kubuntu 11.10 machine. In my experience, I had to select the little down arrow from Aptana 3's Project Explorer, then choose > Customize View > Filters and uncheck **both** *.*files* and *.*resources* to show the *.htaccess* file.

Either one, by itself, would not display the .htaccess file.

Comment: Same on Windows 7 x64 with Aptana Studio 3. Thanks :D