# how to set visible .gitignore in IDE Aptana Studio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, aptana

how to set visible .gitignore in IDE Aptana Studio? 
In console i tried `ls` , but i didn't see it.
I tried `sudo gedit .gitingore` and i can modify it with gedit , but why i can't do it with ide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use sudo to edit files to which you have read+write access.  Secondly, to see the .gitignore, you should use ls -a, which will display all hidden files, i.e. files that start with `.`.  Finally, to answer your question, in the top, right-hand portion of the "App Explorer", there is a drop down menu that you find by clicking the white triangle.  Click on "Customize View", and then uncheck (under Filters) the ".* resources" checkbox (in aptana 3 and above uncheck `.* files`).  Now, it should show hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you uncheck "`.* files`" check box the .gitignore file will be visible in Aptana  (3.3.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete answer to this question, please see the following, which has solutions for both Aptana 2 and 3:

[See answer by DavidYell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166755/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-aptanas-project-view)