# How to show .git directory in aptanas project view

Tags: git, aptana

The stackoverflow answer for [how to show hidden files in aptanas project view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166755/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-aptanas-project-view) works great in Aptana Studio 3, but it still doesn't show the .git directory in the project view. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: usually there is no reason to do anything in the `.git`-folder directly. Why do you want to show it then?

Comment: And http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/204298/654181/#msg_654181 wouldn't help?

Answer (score 1):

While in **Project View** click on the white down arrow (View Menu) in the upper right of the pane

[image]

and then **Customize View...**

Deselect the **.* resources** filter (and also the **.* files** if you also want to view .htaccess etc.)

[image]

and your .git directory will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't see it because you have *Project Sharing* enabled in *Team* menu for that *Project*. The only way I have found to see the `.git` folder is to *Disconnect* from the *Team* menu.