# .htaccess file is invisible in aptana studio 3

Tags: .htaccess, aptana3

I using aptana studio 3, when I create the new php project, in window "Project Explorer" .htaccess file is invisible, (all other files I can see). can someone tell me, how to make this file visible in aptana projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this other stackoverflow post will help you. A .htaccess file is also an hidden file, because of the . in front of the name in all unix systems:

[How to show hidden files in Aptana's Project View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166755/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-aptanas-project-view)

Check it out!